# What does mean $B_s$ independent of $\mathcal F$ where $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra?

Tags: probability

Let $(B_s)_s$ a stochastic process and $\mathcal F$ a $\sigma -$algebra. I often see for example : since $B_s$ is indepandant of $\mathcal F$, $$\mathbb E[B_s]=\mathbb E[B_s\mid \mathcal F],$$
but I don't understand what a random variable independant of a $\sigma -$algebra means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two $\sigma$-algebras $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$ are independent if $\mathbb{P}(A\cap B)=\mathbb{P}(A)\mathbb{P}(B)$ for all $A\in\mathcal{F}$ and $B\in \mathcal{G}$.

Given a random variable $X$, we can define a corresponding $\sigma$-algebra
$$ \sigma(X)=\{X^{-1}(B):B\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\} $$
where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$. We then say that $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{F}$ if $\sigma(X)$ and $\mathcal{F}$ are independent. Intuitively, this means that the information in $\mathcal{F}$ tells us nothing about $X$.

Comment: In other words, this means that for every $B$ in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and every $A$ in $\mathcal F$, $$P(X\in B,A)=P(X\in B)P(A).$$

Answer (score 0):

It mean that, $$\mathbb E[B_s\mid F]=\mathbb E[B_s],$$
for all $F\in \mathcal F$. In general, two $\sigma -$algebra are independent if $$\forall F\in \mathcal F,\forall G\in\mathcal G,\  \mathbb P(F\cap G)=\mathbb P(F)\mathbb P(G).$$